# Difference between "Aligned with" vs "In Alignment With"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, differences

Is there a difference between "aligned with" vs "in alignment with" ?

Context:

you will align US with OUR Inner Truth; clearing all the ways and reasons WE may not be in alignment with OUR Inner Truth

vs

you will align US with OUR Inner Truth; clearing all the ways and reasons WE may not be aligned with OUR Inner Truth

Is there a difference in meaning and intent? if so, which one is better? Do you have a better alternative altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, the meaning is the same. I would say that your second option is clearer
and more concise.

Comment: They do not mean quite the same, esp., in the given context.

Comment: how would they differ then? please clarify!

Comment: @Insight Maybe in the passive voice "The boat is aligned with the slip at the dock" could mean it was not in alignment, and somebody made it so